# Use the same route for with 2 different viewsets, one for writing and one for reading

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 viewsets one for read and other to write:

```py
class MenuReadViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
    queryset = Menu.objects
    filter_class = RelatedEstablishmentFilter
    
    
class MenuWriteViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                       mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                       viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
```

In my `urls.py`

```py
...

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("menus", views.MenuReadViewSet, basename="menu-read")
router.register("menus", views.MenuWriteViewSet, basename="menu-write")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls))
]
```

The problem is, when i send a POST, PUT or DELETE , returns this response:

```js
{
  "detail": "Method <METHOD> not allowed"
}
```

It seems that the route considers only the first viewset. Exists a simple way to solve this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? Do you want to use different filter, queryset or serializer for GET than other methods?

Comment: Because i've different permissions classes for read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment

> different permissions classes for read and write

Just use different permission classes but within a single `ModelViewSet`.

```
class MenuViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
    queryset = Menu.objects
    filter_class = RelatedEstablishmentFilter
    permission_classes = [MenuPermissionClass]
    
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ['retrieve', 'list']:
            perms = [ReadOnlyMenuPermission]
        else:
            perms = self.permission_classes
        return [p() for p in perms]
```

Or handle it in your permission.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS

...

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj) -> bool:
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            # todo: ro permission
        ...
```